# Compress a Mysqldump that is SSH'd to another machine

Tags: bash, optimization, shell, ssh, mysql

I have the following:

```
 mysqldump -u xxxx 
           -h localhost 
           --password=xxxxx databasename | 
           ssh username@00.000.00.202 "dd of=httpdocs/backup`date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'`.sql"
```

...which SSH's a mysqldump to a remote machine.

I need to compress the mysqldump before it is SSH'd as the dump is 500mb and its eating up my bandwidth allowance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `mysqldump ... | gzip -9 | ssh ...`

or

> `mysqldump ... | bzip2 -9 | ssh ...`

or, if you want it uncompressed on the other end

> `mysqldump ... | bzip2 -9 | ssh machine "bzip2 -d >..."`
>
> `mysqldump ... | gzip -9 | ssh machine "gzip -d >..."`

Answer (score 7):

You can add the `-C` flag to the `ssh` call to automatically compress the transmitted data.

Comment: This is interesting, I was thinking only of doing a zip of the file on the fly.

Comment: That will be a joke of compression, though.

Comment: @hacker: Any special reason that you think this compression will be not good enough? Just that you would prefer a `-9` flag for gzip?

Comment: sth, Actually, I would prefer -9 for bzip2 if I want to save bandwidth ;-) (and you can specify gipz level to ssh, anyway), but this is not what I meant here. Now that I think of it I am not sure if I was right, anyway. But my guess is that ssh does compression in shorter chunks - otherwise it wouldn't be half as responsive as it is. And doing compression in small chunks of course would prevent it from efficiently compressing the stream. If you seriously know what you're talking about I would love to learn I'm wrong here (if I am).

Answer (score 2):

You need to call gzip between mysqldump and ssh, like:

```
mysqldump [mysql options] | gzip | ssh [ssh options]
```

I would recommend changing the saved file extension to ".sql.gz" as well.

Comment: should be `.sql.gz` then - the outermost encapsulation at the end.

Comment: Good catch, I typo'd that in accidently. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered and accepted, but I thought you might find this an interesting alternative.

Percona's OpenSource [xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtrabackup:xtrabackup_manual#details) application will perform compressed (TAR) backups on the fly - along with lots of other interesting things.

I couldn't find an anchor on the page, but scroll down to "Compressed Backups".